# checkbox change event instantly changing text underline

Tags: jquery

I want checkbox change event to underline my sample text. However it's not working. I added a fiddle into it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checkbox').change(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            $('.text').css('text-decoration', 'underline')
        }
        else {
            $('.text').css('text-decorationr', 'none')
        }
        }) 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JsUWv/731/

Comment: Selector is wrong: `$('.checkbox1')` should be `$('#checkbox1')`

Comment: Check your console for errors. Also the `div` tag is not a self-closing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selector is wrong: `$('.checkbox1')` should be `$('#checkbox1')`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkbox1').change(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            $('.text').css('text-decoration', 'underline')
        }
        else {
            $('.text').css('text-decoration', 'none')
        }
        }) 
    });
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/JsUWv/720/

**Later edit:**
Here's a `CSS` only approach if you want: http://jsfiddle.net/JsUWv/732/

```
#checkbox1:checked + .text{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

PS: I wonder how this got to revision `720`

Comment: Oh you were quicker, 724.

Comment: Because you tried 719 times to get it right? :p j/k. I think jsfiddle takes any and all revisions into account when incrementing, including ones that aren't yours.

Comment: You're right about the selectors (though there's invalid HTML too `<div />text</div>`), but I'd suggest a slightly different approach: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JsUWv/725/

Comment: I haven't tried 719 times. It was another person who was using another example before me :))

Comment: @HakanErbaslar For sure, I was just playing around. :) Take a peek at DavidThomas' comment. He provided a nice refactor.

Comment: See the update if you want a much simpler, no-javascript solution.

Comment: I saw css-only solution too. Thank you very much. picked as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You were prematurely closing your `.text` DIV, Had an extra set of brackets in the JavaScript, calling the wrong `checkbox` selector ("#checkbox", for the ID), and a misspelling of "text-decoration" in the `else` conditional... Take a look at this and compare.

http://jsfiddle.net/JsUWv/723/